# Python: No such file or directory error (Mac user)

Tags: python, macos

I am a Mac user and I am trying to change the cwd of the current directory to the below but it is giving me the error. Could you please suggest me how I can fix this error?

```
os.chdir('/Users/hdummi/Desktop/')

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-12308fa290ee> in <module>()
----> 1 os.chdir('/Users/hdummi/Desktop/')

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/hdummi/Desktop/'
```

The current path says something like:

```
import os
os.getcwd()

'/export/hda3/borgletdata/dirs/'
```

Comment: Are you perhaps on a different volume or disk?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess based on your current path I would say you are ssh'd into a Linux computer or otherwise running the script remotely so you can't chdir into the Desktop folder on your local Mac.

Comment: Thanks Reilly. I am actually ssh'd into a Linux computer. How can I overcome this error?

Comment: If you need to access files from your local machine you will need to copy them to your remote machine.